# iOS Firebase IS_ADS_ENABLED flag in GoogleService-Info.plist file

Tags: ios, firebase, configuration, plist

When adding `Firebase` support to the iOS app, Firebase generates this `GoogleService-Info.plist` file.

One of the flags in this file is `IS_ADS_ENABLED` which defaults to `true`.

I can't find any documentation of this flag (on the website nor in `FIROptions`). Does anyone knows what does it do and when can I disable it?

Comment: It looks like they now set that flag to `false` by default. But now I am worried to turn it off in production...

Comment: Mine has been updated to false as well in production, but it is safe as the key is not used anymore in Firebase projects

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Firebase support gives this answer about `IS_ADS_ENABLED`

> The `IS_ADS_ENABLED` key was previously used on Firebase projects that
>   are using Google Ads features. However, **it's deprecated** now, but **your
>   app should have no issues whether it's set to true or false.** 
>   We're still looking for solutions to remove this for all projects to avoid confusion. As of now, we are yet to find out any details or timelines as to when it will be implemented

Yes, you can disable it. I have disabled it in my project.