# What happens if I disable IS_GCM_ENABLED key to false in Google-Service-info.plist

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have application which has Firebase Push Notifications.

I changed `IS_GCM_ENABLED` key to false in Google-Service-info.plist on Xcode.

But push notifications works perfectly and why push notification works even I changed key to false?

Could you explain for what we use these keys in Google-Service-info.plist

`IS_GCM_ENABLED,
IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED,
IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED,
IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED,
IS_ADS_ENABLED,`

As I know GCM changed to FCM and Why in Google-Service-info.plist we use `IS_GCM_ENABLED` not `IS_FCM_ENABLED`?

Why `IS_FCM_ENABLED` key doesn't exists in Google-Service-info.plist?

Comment: about IS_ADS_ENABLED you can see [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380776/ios-firebase-is-ads-enabled-flag-in-googleservice-info-plist-file) .

Answer (score 2):

IS_GCM_ENABLED is related to the both - FCM/GCM function services.

Other fields:

IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED - for App Invites feature services

IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED - for Google Analytics feature services. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549074/firebase-for-ios-googleservice-info-plist-property-is-analytics-enabled-set-t)

IS_ADS_ENABLED - for Google Ads feature services

Unfortunately, there is no much public documentation about this. But Firebase has great [support](https://firebase.google.com/support/). They provided me with all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because your notifications sent through Apple Push Notification Center...